# How to make Select Where statement in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows, ado.net

I want to select all customer information where customerid = the selected customerid stored in the combo box and show the result in datagridview I tried this code but the gridview doesnot show result.

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
      int id = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
string cmdstring=string.Format("select *from customers where customer_id={0}",id);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstring,con);

        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",id);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //da.Fill(ds, "customers");
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["customers"];

        con.Open();
         SqlDataReader red = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        con.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = red;




        button = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        button.HeaderText = "edit";
        button.Tag = ds.Tables["customers"].Columns["customer_id"];

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(button);

    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use string concatenation to create your query; you're opening yourself up to SQL injection.  You should use a parameterized query.

Comment: Can you wrap your code where you are doing cmd.ExecuteReader within a Try Catch..

Comment: first lets start with getting your DataTable to return properly, then we can move to getting the Column information it's hard to tell what's or where your code is Throwing Errors without proper Exception handling

Answer (score 3):

you could always make a DataBase Class and if you need to refactor this Class to pass in Connection String or read Connection string from .Config File you can use this as a template to get started plus it's a lot cleaner 
Notice that I am returning a DataTable you can use this if you like just a suggestion

```
public class ClassDataManagement 
{ 
   public DataTable GetData(string sqlcmdString, string connString)
   {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmdString, cn);
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       con.Open();
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       da.Fill(dt);
       return dt;
   } 
}
```

if you want to use DataSet instead of DataTable replace where i have DataTable with
or change the method to return a DataSet like this below

```
   public DataSet GetData(string sqlcmdString, string connString)
   {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmdString, cn);
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       con.Open();
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       da.Fill(ds);
       return ds;
   }
```

after returning the ds you will need to bind it like this

```
   dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
   dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that you're not getting any data because you're closing the connection before binding, and because you're using an incompatible type as your data source:

```
    con.Close();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = red;
```

Set the data source prior to closing the connection, or at least be sure to populate the data (for data readers, the data are populated as you enumerate).  Additionally, [DataGridView.DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) indicates that it must use one of four interfaces: IList, IListSource, IBindingList, and IBindingListSource.  SqlDataReader does not support these.  I recommend reading [DataAdapters and DataReaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms254931%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), as this outlines some of the features that are for populating this kind of control.

Comment: he looks like he's missing a .Fill() method as well

Comment: Ah, I figured there was probably a method for that, but I wasn't familiar enough with DataGridView to know its name (I always thought it was DataBind() but didn't see it on the class).

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I figure before you can DataBind() it must have "DATA" to bind to..

Comment: Well, he calls SqlCommand.ExecuteReader().  That will initiate a streaming reader which will contain data if he enumerates over it.  But he's binding to the reader, which is not allowed.